# Is it ok to use a semphore as a global pause for worker threads?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool

I'm thinking of using a semaphore as a pause mechanism for a pool of worker threads like so:

```
// main thread
for N jobs:
    semaphore.release()
    create and start worker

// worker thread
while (not done)
    semaphore.acquire()
    do_work
    semaphore.release()
```

Now, if I want to pause all workers, I can acquire the entire count available in the semaphore. I'm wondering it that is better than:

```
if (paused)
    paused_mutex.lock
    wait for condition (paused_mutex)
do_work
```

Or is there a better solution?

I guess one downside of doing it with the semaphore is that the main thread will block until all workers release. In my case, the unit of work per iteration is very small so that probably won't be a problem.

Update: to clarify, my workers are database backups that act like file copies. The while(not quit) loop quits when the file has been successfully copied. So to relate it to the traditional worker-waits-for-condition to get work: my workers wait for a needed file copy and the while loop you see is doing the work requested. You could think of my do_work above as do_piece_of_work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the semaphore approach is that the worker threads have to constantly check for work. They are eating up all the available CPU resources. It is better to use a mutex and a condition (signalling) variable (as in your second example) so that the threads are woken up only when they have something to do.

It is also better to hold the mutex for as short a time as possible. The traditional way to do this is to create a WORK QUEUE and to use the mutex to synchronize queue inserts and removals. The main thread inserts into the work queue and wakes up the worker. The worker acquires the mutex, removes an item from the queue, then release the mutex. NOW the worker performs the action. This maximizes the concurrency between the worker threads and the main thread.
Here is an example:

```
// main thread
create signal variable
create mutex

for N jobs:
    create and start worker

while (wait for work)
    // we have something to do
    create work item
    mutex.acquire();
    insert_work_into_queue(item);
    mutex.release();

    //tell the workers
    signal_condition_variable()

//worker thread
while (wait for condition)
    mutex.acquire();
    work=remove_item_from_queue();
    mutex.release();

    if (work) do(work);
```

This is a simple example where all the worker threads are awakened, even though only one worker will actually succeed in getting work off of the queue. If you want even more efficiency, use an array of condition variables, one per worker thread and then just signal the "next" one, using an algorithm for "next" that is as simple or as complex as you want.

Comment: My workers are database backups. They give me an incremental step function for performing work until they report done. That's why I didn't want to always wait on each iteration. Of course, I could setup the database backup objects outside of the workers and queue them for incremental work similar to your code. However, I want them to run as fast as possible in the background unless a high priority event occurs that requires me to pause or stop the backups.